# ImportError: Couldn't import Django in creating a database

Tags: django

I am trying to create database using  django but getting following error:

```
(myvenv) C:\Users\hp\djangogirls>myvenv\Scripts\activate

(myvenv) C:\Users\hp\djangogirls> python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
  from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
   ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and 
available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to 
activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: do `pip install django`

Comment: thanks a lot brother it helped!

Comment: welcome posting as answer please accept if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Type `pip list` and, if you don't see **Django** in the list, type `pip install django`

Answer (score 0):

do `pip install django` to install any package replace package name for  package error